# Scala Macro Annotations - Why doesn't my class appear to be updated when I use it as a type parameter?

Tags: scala, type-parameter, scala-macros, salat

I used Eugene Burmako's macro annotation example from [Macro Paradise](https://github.com/scalamacros/sbt-example-paradise) (thanks Eugene!) and modified here it to add a `val` to an empty class [**here**](http://bit.ly/1aVivIn).

As an instance, I can call the new `val` as expected. But when I try to use the updated class as a type parameter, e.g. in [Salat](https://github.com/novus/salat)(parses a Scala sig) or [Scalavro](https://github.com/GenslerAppsPod/scalavro)(uses 2.10 reflection), then the class appears still empty (i.e. as if the `val` was never added).

Since Salat parses the Scala signature, I checked and it's shorter than a normal signature by about 30 entries, and the order of the entries differs. Yet it *does* appear that the signature includes info about the added `val`.

So how come the new val info is not accessible, and is there any way to make it so? Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding a val into a template doesn't automatically make it a constructor parameter. To do that, the constructor itself also needs to be adjusted. Luckily we have quasiquotes, which greatly simplify this task in comparison with manual tree construction.

```
case q"$mods class $name[..$tparams](..$first)(...$rest) extends ..$parents { $self => ..$body }" :: Nil =>
  val CASEACCESSOR = (1 << 24).toLong.asInstanceOf[FlagSet]
  val PARAMACCESSOR = (1 << 29).toLong.asInstanceOf[FlagSet]
  val helloMods = Modifiers(CASEACCESSOR | PARAMACCESSOR | DEFAULTPARAM)
  val helloVal = q"""$helloMods val x: String = "hello macro!""""
  q"$mods class $name[..$tparams](..$first, $helloVal)(...$rest) extends ..$parents { $self => ..$body }"
```

Note a couple of quirks: 1) we need to set CASEACCESSOR and PARAMACCESSOR flags that aren't present in the official API in order to avoid crash in Salat, 2) we need to set DEFAULTPARAM in order to make sure that scalac recognizes our default parameter as default, 3) default parameters can't have their types inferred, so we need to explicitly provide String here.

Comment: Fantastic! I needed that example of quasiquotes, thanks a bunch (also, the good error messages are helping me grok). I've updated my project to show the working example.

Comment: With latest quasiquotes you don't need any of the caseaccessor|paramacessor magic, those flags will be set automatically behind the scenes.

Comment: p.s. Actually DEFAULTPARAM isn't needed either. Just create a val and splice it in parameter position and it should work just fine.

Comment: Looks like I still need DEFAULTPARAM in some cases with user-defined classes/types? ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/julianpeeters/8405121)) cc @DenShabalin

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time for paradise plugin atm. There is a plan to backport latest features some time around 2.11 release.